# access collection in mongodb through native driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have set up a mongo database and have successfully connected through the native driver like so:

```
var mongo=require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db;
mongo.connect('mongodb://path/to/db',function(err,db1){
if(err){
    console.log(err);
}else{
    console.log('mongo connection established');
    db=db1;
}
```

});

I then try to update a preexisting collection:

```
if(db){db.test.save({hello:'world'});}
```

I get an error saying `cannot call save of undefined`.

Comment: Try with db.collection('test').save({hello:'world'});

Comment: That worked! I also had to add a callback `db.collection("test").save({hello:'world'},callback)`

Comment: I have a question about SO etiquette. If someone answers my question through a comment like Hector how do I give them credit since there is no answer to mark correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following syntax:

```
db.collection('test').save({hello:'world'}, callback);
```

In Node.js you need to use the collection method to access the collection (which is different from the MongoDB shell)